# set another CDMA operator in a verizon wireless galaxy tab

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, sim-unlocking, cdma

Got a galaxy tab 7 SCHI800BKV verizon wireless tab. It has no rim/sim port. Question is if I root the device will it be possible to set my country's CDMA operator in the device?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device may have to be unlocked first. Rooting will not Unlock the device. You will also need information from the network you want to run the device on. Like if the device is supported on their network, if they are able to active the device (they will be able to tell you if they support it if you give them the ESN/MEID) and what their mobile carrier code is (SID/NID/MCC).

I did find [this info](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/samsung-galaxy-tab/133098-verizon-galaxy-tab-use-india.html#post1405581) that may help once it is unlocked:

> From here, I will walk you through programming the tablet for ota activation with that carrier.
>   If its the verizon galaxy tab, to get to the programming menu go to the notepad and type **772 to get to the manual programming.
>
> the spc code will always be 000000
>
> from here touch down 3 times
>   clear out the directory number with 10 0's
>   then hit down
>   then clear out the msin with 10 0's
>   from here touch down
>   here you will change the system id to what is necessary for that carrier.
>   then you will hit left or right and then enter
>   then hit down 4 times and you should see mcc, put the mcc number here
>   then hit down 4 times, and the home sid should match the one you input, then you will change the NID for that carrier as well
>   then you will hit down 64 times, and make sure cdma homesys reg is yes
>   then hit down 6 times to where it says slot cycle index, change this to 1 by hitting touch here and clear it and hit 1
>   then exit service

Comment: you would have to call Verizon, I would think.

Comment: I called verizon they say the ESN is good but they won't unlock it for me. Can I unlock it myself?

Comment: take a look at [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhiDY_FTt9s), it may work for this model too, I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Fast gsm also says sorry. Probably I am out of luck

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, rooting is completely unrelated to unlocking.

CDMA unlocking is also more difficult than SIM unlocking a GSM phone, and CDMA phones need to be activated on the network, unlike sticking a SIM in an unlocked GSM phone and doing whatever you want.  You'll need help from both carriers (Verizon to unlock, your carrier to activate) in order to do this.

Comment: If I root the device will it not automatically unlock from verizon? If the answer is NO, do they (verizon) cooperates in the unlock process? (I purchased this from ebay, how can I do it?)

Comment: @newcomer Rooting won't do anything to unlock it. I don't much about Verizon's customer service, but it might be possible for your local carrier to handle the transfer from Verizon.  If the ESN is "dirty" (the device was lost or stolen) then you're probably completely out of luck ... this often happens with *used* devices from eBay, at least.

Comment: OK I called verizon they say the ESN is good but they don't unlock it for me. Can I unlock it myself?

Comment: @newcomer I would doubt it; from what I understand only the carriers have access to whatever tools they have that keeps track of the ESN globally.